# Ajax call not succeeding after function call

Tags: javascript, ajax, codeigniter

I am attempting to load dynamic data based on the specific URI segment thats on the page.

Heres my Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(function() {
        load_custom_topics();
    });

    $('#topics_form').submit(function() {
        var topic = document.getElementById('topics_filter').value
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'ajax/update_session_topic',
            dataType: 'json', 
            data: { topic: topic },
                success: function(){
                    load_custom_topics()
                }
        });
        return false;
    });

    function load_custom_topics(){
        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'ajax/load_custom_topics',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {},
                success: function (html) {
                    $('div.topics_filter').html(html['content']);
                    get_threads();
                }
        });
    }

    function get_threads(){
        var page = document.getElementById('page').value
        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'ajax/get_threads',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {page: page},
            success: function (html) {
                $('div#thread_list').html(html['content']);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

So, as you can see, on page load, it kicks off `load_custom_topics` which runs just fine.  Its then supposed to call `get_threads()`.  This is where the thing stops, and I get no data.

Get_threads()

```
public function get_threads()
{
    $session = $this->session->userdata('active_topic');
    if ($this->input->post('page') == '1')
    {
        $data['list'] = $this->right_model->thread_list_all();
        $data['test'] = "all";
    } else {
        $data['list'] = $this->right_model->thread_list_other($session);
        $data['test'] = "not all";
    }
    if ($data['list'] == FALSE)
    {
        $content = "no hits";
    } else {
    $content = $this->load->view('right/thread_list', $data, TRUE);
    }
    $data['content'] = $content;
    $this->output->set_content_type('application/json')->set_output(json_encode($data));
}
```

While I create the 'page' dynamically, the HTML outputs to this:

`<div name="page" value="1"></div>`

Any reason why `get_threads()` is not running?

Comment: Does it call 'get_threads' on the server?

Comment: Not that I think it is your problem, but you have two document ready handlers specified. `$(document).ready(function() { ... }` and `$(function() { ... }` are the same thing.

Comment: Yes, In fact, it[ the controller code: `ajax/get_threads`] was working fine until I added the `<div name=page>` and started passing it through the app via getelementID

Comment: Can you use firebug/chrome/fiddler etc to get the json output from the controller method and post that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does not have an ID. It has a name.

```
<div name="page" value="1"></div>
```

This means that your request for `getElementById` is failing. So this line of code should be showing a *TypeError* in your console.

```
var page = document.getElementById('page').value
```

Comment: Thank you, I just caught myself this and was headed here to inform you all of my stupidity ;).  Thank you again